# Can't we factor out a constant in the cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I have the vectors $A=a\hat e_x$ and $B=a\hat e_y$, so 
$$
A\times B =
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a &0
\end{vmatrix}=\hat za^2
$$
*Q1: But why is the following wrong*
\begin{align}
A\times B &=a\hat e_x\times a\hat e_y\\
&=(a\hat e_x)\times (a\hat e_y) \tag 1\\ 
&=(a\hat e_x)\times (\hat e_ya) \tag 2\\
&=a(\hat e_x)\times (\hat e_y)a \tag 3\\
&=a((\hat e_x)\times (\hat e_y)) \tag 4\\
&=a(\hat e_x\times \hat e_y) \tag 5\\
&=a\hat e_z \quad ?
\end{align}

*Q2: Also, why is this wrong*
\begin{align}
A\times B &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a &0
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=
a
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
1 & 0 & 0\\ \tag 6
0 & 1 &0
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=a\hat z \quad ?
\end{align}

Comment: They are wrong because the cross-product isn't defined that way.

Comment: You can take out a common factor of a single row in a determinant. Here you take out the common factor from two rows. That's two factors, each equal to $a$. Therefore you get $a^2$ altogether.

Comment: @Bernard Massé Why do you say that ? it is a form that is used rather usually in physics. Have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133311

Comment: @ Jean Marie. What I meant was the cross-product is defined in such a way (be it done by determinants or another way) that product by a constant is not distributive over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$=a(\hat e_x)\times (\hat e_y)a \tag 3$$
>   $$=a((\hat e_x)\times (\hat e_y)) \tag 4$$

What happens here...?

You may be mixing it up with the distributive property of the cross product over *addition*.

> *Q2: Also, why is this wrong*
>   \begin{align}
> A\times B &=
> \begin{vmatrix}
> \hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
> a & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & a &0
> \end{vmatrix} \\
> &=
> a
> \begin{vmatrix}
> \hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
> 1 & 0 & 0\\ \tag 6
> 0 & 1 &0
> \end{vmatrix}\\
> &=a\hat z \quad ?
> \end{align}

For starters, the determinant notation for computing the cross product is actually just a mnemonic. But if you want to use properties of determinants, you should note that the determinant is linear in its columns and rows, so for example:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
\color{purple}{k}d& \color{purple}{k}e & \color{purple}{k}f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}=\color{purple}{k}\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d& e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}$$
This means that if you want to factor out the $a$, you do that for the second **and** the third row:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
\color{blue}{a}& 0 & 0\\
0 & \color{red}{a} &0
\end{vmatrix}=\color{blue}{a}\color{red}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 &0
\end{vmatrix}=a^2\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 &0
\end{vmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that by [**cross product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition) definition

$$A\times B =a\hat e_x\times a\hat e_y=a^2( e_x\times \hat e_y)$$

and by the [**properties of the determinant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant)

$$A\times B =
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a &0
\end{vmatrix} =
a^2
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat e_x &\hat e_y & \hat e_z \\
1 & 0 & 0\\ \tag 6
0 & 1 &0
\end{vmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument is wrong because you lost an $a$ between lines (3) and (4).

Your second argument is wrong because line (6) should have $a^2$, not $a$. You can confirm this just by evaluating the determinant, as you did at the beginning of your post. You have somehow misunderstood the rules for removing common factors from determinants.